# Running bash inside cronjob

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

I have this cronjob to run every minute

```
*/1 * * * * root sh /test.sh
```

My /test.sh logs the result of "top" and "free" command. It works fine when I run it manually on terminal with "sh /teste.sh" and saves the output to a nice file, however when the cron job runs it only saves the result of the command "free" below. Check this please:

```
printf "\n" >> "log_lojar_top_free.txt"
printf %s "$(date)" >> "log_lojar_top_free.txt"
printf '\t' >> "log_lojar_top_free.txt"
top -b -n 3 -d 1 | grep "Cpu" |  tail -n 1 | awk '/^%Cpu\(s\)/ {printf $2}' >> "log_lojar_top_free.txt"
printf '\t' >> "log_lojar_top_free.txt"
free | awk '/^Mem:/ {printf $7}' >> "log_lojar_top_free.txt"
```

What is the error that is causing that only the last line (free) to have it's output loged?

Comment: if you want to run a bash script then use bash, not sh.  they're not the same thing.  even if sh is a symlink to bash, bash behaves differently if called as sh rather than bash.

Comment: you can do as cas suggests either by prefixing in crontab with `/bin/bash` instead of `sh`, or by starting your script with a shebang line:
`#!/bin/bash` - see if it behaves better once you definitely have it running under bash and not some other shell. Another possibility is that you aren't looking in the right place for the output file. The cron job is running as root and since you didn't specify an output directory, only a file, it will probably save it at / - not a good place to use generally. Oh and BTW you don't need the /1.

Comment: A quick check shows that my implementation of `crond` writes to the user's home directory. In my case, for root that's `/root`.

Answer (score 16):

As suggested by others, try to direct use the bash shebang in your script or prefix by using `bash` instead of `sh`. For I don't know what system you're actually running, I recently ran into trouble calling a script usign `/bin/sh -c myscript.sh` under ubuntu which is a debian derivate which uses `dash` instead of `bash`.

Maybe this is the key to your problem.

EDIT: I've got it working with this crontab entry, done as root with `crontab -e`:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash -c "/test.sh"
```

Comment: Good catch re `dash`. However, the OP's script appears to run equivalently under `bash`, `sh` (for some value of `sh`) and `dash`.

Comment: Or single quotation marks can be used too: `/bin/bash -c '/test.sh'` if no special meaning characters are required.

Answer (score 0):

This version works for me. However, as your own script also works here I'm not entirely sure this will fix your problem.

System-wide crontab entry (omit the `root` field if this is root's own crontab, as accessed with `crontab -e`):

```
* * * * * root /root/test.sh
```

As far as I can detemine, your script takes the third iteration from `top` and collects the CPU usermode percentage. It also collects the cached memory value from `free`. Here I've dispensed with `free` and extracted the same value from the third iteration of `top`. Copy this script to /root/test.sh (and make it executable):

```
#!/bin/bash
top -b -n 3 -d 1 |
    awk -v date="$(date)" '
        /^%Cpu/ {cpu=$2}
        /cached Mem/ {cached=$9}
        END {printf "\n%s\t%s\t%s", date, cpu, cached}
    ' >> /root/log_lojar_top_free.txt
```

Make the script executable:

```
chmod +x /root/test.sh
```